# Replace jsonNode entry with it's child node

Tags: java, json, jackson, couchbase

I'm trying to convert a JsonNode object returned by my couchbase query like this:

```
{
  "_object": {
    "_nodeFactory": {
      "_cfgBigDecimalExact": false
    },
    "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode",
    "_children": {
      "Name": {
        "_value": "Kapil",
        "_class": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode"
      }
    }
  },
  "_predicate": "http://joebloggs",
  "_class": "com.dreamworks.pam.gsplus.entity.GsJsonStore",
  "_subject": "joebloggs"
}
```

To a jsonNode like this:

```
{
  "_object": {
      "Name": "Kapil"
  },
  "_predicate": "http://web.studio.dreamworks.com/data/@user/joebloggs"
  "_subject": "joebloggs"
}
```

My idea is to replace a node with it's child node, for example, replacing `_children` node in the above example with it's child node `Name`, replacing `_value` node with its child etc. Is there anyway I can do this? I've looked at the `replace` method of the ObjectNode class but it doesn't suit my case. I'm looking for someway to do this without traversing through each node.

PS: The `_object` field is a schema-less json object, so any solution to do with a POJO wouldn't work for me.

Comment: So basically are you trying to replace parts of a JSON documents without replacing the whole document? BTW, you using JAVA right?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Java.